# Wide image vertical alignment in 1 page latex

Tags: graphics

I have a very tall image (591 x 8383) which I want to put as Appendix in my Latex document. How can I place this picture vertically aligned on a single (really big) page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Rotating**

You can rotate an image by using `angle` in the `\includegraphics` optional arguments. For instance this will rotate your image `90` degrees anti-clock wise.

```
\includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c]{image}
```

Here `origin=c` sets the axis of the rotation, to be the center of the image.

Another option is to use the `rotating` package and its `sideways` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \includegraphics{image}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

**Scaling**

To make the image fit in your page, you can use the optional argument `scale`, in the `\includegraphics` command, like this

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
```

The previous code scales the image by 50%.

**Changing Locally page size**

To change page size locally you can use `\eject \pdfpagewidth=3in \pdfpageheight=10in` just at the begging of the page before adding anything on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Normal page

\eject \pdfpagewidth=3in \pdfpageheight=10in    
Tall page

\eject \pdfpagewidth=20in \pdfpageheight=3in    
Wide page
\end{document}
```

**Solution**

To conclude, you can use

```
\eject \pdfpagewidth=3in \pdfpageheight=10in%adjust dimensions according to your needs 
\includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c]{image}
```

which will rotate and scale your image. Change `90` and `0.5` according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, however I don't want my image to be scaled, I want it to be displayed in full size (this will take up to 2-3 normal pages)

Comment: @Dennis : Do you want the images to be split across 2 or 3 pages or do you want to change the page size and fit the whole image in there?

Comment: @Thonas , i am sorry for my late response. I want to change the page size and fit the whole image in there. Thank you

Comment: So basically my image is 8383px of height, I want this to fit on one page